# how to insert the data from delta table to a variable in order to apply drools rule on them

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am using spark with scala in which I am getting streaming data from eventhubs and then storing them in delta table. In order to apply drools rule on them, I need to pass them through variables... I am stuck where I have to get the data from delta table to variable.

Comment: Are rules applied to the individual rows separately or to whole dataset?

Comment: To individual rows

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what data you need to pass to that drools rules, and what you need to return.  You can either use:

- [User defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html) - you define a function that will receive one or more parameters (column values of specific rows). ([more examples](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-udf/))
- Use `map` function of `Dataset` / `Dataframe` class to process the whole Row ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map%5BU%5D(func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D), and [examples](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-vs-flatmap-with-examples/))

Answer (score 0):

Delta Tables can be read into DataFrames.  A variable can be assigned to point to the DataFrame.

```py
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("some/delta/path")
```

Once the Delta Table is read, you can apply your custom transformations:

```py
transformed_df = df.transform(first_transform).transform(second_transform)
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.